# Vuetify show select options nicely

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-select

My select options covering my label *"Download"*.

[image]

I've tried to add `offset-y`, but the result is still bad.

```
<v-select offset-y dense outlined :items="downloadOptions" label="Download" v-model="downloadOption"></v-select>
```

Any hints for me to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `menu-props` prop.

For boolean values like `offset-y` you can just pass a string.

```html
<v-select menu-props="offset-y"></v-select>
```

Here is the corresponding [Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props).

Answer (score 2):

you can try with css  Here is the code.

```css
.v-text-field--outlined.v-input--dense .v-label--active {
    transform: translateY(-26px) scale(.75);
}
```